# In Android quick settings menu why is Cellular data on/off option in a second screen?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, android, user-expectation, toggle

In the quick settings menu that slides down from Android, all settings are activated or deactivated tapping the icon. With the exception of the sounds settings which needs to be choosen between 3 different settings. (Also the portrait/landscape mode is not actually on/off).

This is not the case of the Cellular data which **when tapped brings the user to a secondary screen where there is the toogle button** and information.

In the case of Bluetooth or Wifi to enter this secondary screen the user has to tap the dropdown below the icon. There the user can get more information or choose which network/device to connect.

What is the reason for making the Cellular data on/off option less convenient adding an extra step, breaking also the schema of the other buttons?

[image]

Comment: Its a confusing screen full of numbers which mean nothing to me.  I hadn't spotted that there is an on / off button for mobile data up at the top right after having the phone for 3 years !

Comment: Actually,  it's more than just those options. When I tap my Bluetooth icon, it goes to a secondary screen. When I tap my wifi (I'm currently not in range of a saved network) it goes to a list of networks. When I tap my battery icon it shows a chart of usage and has a 'stamina mode' toggle. I agree that it's confusing to have some buttons be straight toggles while others navigate to a secondary screen, but it's not like mobile data is the only one that stands out. Personally? I'd go for tap to toggle, Press for details.

Answer (score -1):

It is all about primary actions, since someone is using a smartphone the chances of him disabling data is very less, we all want to be constantly getting updates, so it is moved to the second screen.

Hardcode users can just tap the cellular icon once to disable and enable data quickly.